# Storing user location coordinates and other user specific data in session in flask

Tags: python-2.7, web, flask

I want to store user's location coordinates in the session
I am using Flask Micro Framework.

```
    from flask import session as sess
    geolocator = GoogleV3()
    @app.route('/location', methods = ['POST'])
    def location():
          latitude = request.json['latitude']
          longitude = request.json['longitude']
          address = geolocator.reverse(str(latitude)+ "," + str(longitude),exactly_one = True)
          sess['lat'] = float(latitude)
          sess['long'] = float(longitude)
```

This is the code that I have written to store the location in session
I don't think this is the correct way because I am not able to retrive the stored data and this data is different for every user and I am using this coords for further calculation that is to find garage.
Below is the code for the same.

```
    def find_garage():
          garageList = session.query(Garage)
          user_coords = (float(sess['lat']), float(sess['long']))
          for garage in garageList:
                d = haversine(user_coords,(float(garage.locationX),float(garage.locationY)))
                if d <= 0.5:
                    sess['garagename'] = garage.name
                    sess['garagecontact'] = garage.contactnumber
                    send_email("myemail@example.com","Location:",str(sess['garagename']))
                    break
```

I am running this `find_garage()`method once the user submits a post request about the type of service needed.But I am not able to retrieve the `garagename` and also `lat long`stored in session and I get the `KeyError`
Maybe this is due to refresh that happens.
Please Note:I am not using any other line of code for using session.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sess.get('lat',0)` instead of `sess['lat']` and `sess.get('long',0)` instead of `sess['long']` because at the first call to `find_garage` the session dict may be empty.

The get methode of a dict returns 0 (optional second argument, if empty it return None) if the key is not in the dict.

Use the 0 or an other default value for the two keys if they are not set.

Comment: Regarding the `KeyError` yes.@rajendrakadam

Comment: I don't want the default value to be zero.I should get the value that I stored @SebastianStigler can you point to some resources where they teach me or show how to use sessions in flask to store data server side for each user